# How to handle the exceptions that thrown by a propertygrid?

Tags: c#, exception, propertygrid

I have a Winforms PropertyGrid in c# that controls the data that getted and setted from an embedded system.

I wrote the queries about the device (GetFrequency,SetPowerLimit,SetACCurrent e.c.) as Properties so that i can bind the data without writing another method for each command inside the Form that i want to create.

The PropertyGrid works really nice, i mean it shows all the data that i need and lets me change their values. But not always of course.

Because of this black box situtation of the device that have to work on, the program halts normally at some points. (i.e. when you turn the device off.)

For example, here is a value that i have to read frequently from the device. "Simin"

```
    [Category("Editable Values"), Description("Sets the minimum select...")]
    public Ampere Simin
    {
        get
        {...}
        set
        {...}
    }
```

Within the Getters and Setters i have these get methods that establishes the connection between pc and the device. And they are the actual source of exceptions that i take mostly.

Like this

```
if (!_port.IsOpen)
        {
            throw new HuettingerException(Localisation.Error_PortClosed);
        }
```

or this

```
// Read first 4 bytes
            if (_port.Read(inputv, 0, 4) != 4)
            {
                throw new HuettingerException(Localisation.Error_NoConnection);
            }
```

So i have three abstraction layers and i take the exceptions from the machine side (like the one shown above) while i try to read some data. I tried to catch some of them at the beginning like

```
 public DeviceUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {                
            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = device;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException te) // i tried other exceptions too
        {
            MessageBox.Show(te.Message);
        }
```

at initialization of the winform but it didn't work.

My problem is, if it was a Button or a Textfield, i could easily catch the exceptions in the event methods, but i have no idea about handling an exception that thrown by a PropertyGrid.

Any opinions?

Comment: My dear first Downvoter, you could at least leave a comment. But you don't like to see people improving themselves do you?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and I would probably not have downvoted - but it might be due to the lack of some code illustrating how you've used the PropertyGrid.

Comment: When are these exceptions being thrown? When the value is being edited by the user in the property grid or when you are updating the value through some event in your code?

Comment: @iandotkelly, My bad. But thanxalot for the advice

Comment: @3yanlist1bos - no problem at all.  Just like to see people get good help here.

Comment: @iandotkelly :) the opposite of what i said, i guess. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: The `device` class is supposed to represent the data on the device. Is this correct? Then why is this class handling the communication with the device. The communication should be in another class that populates or uses the `device` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception being thrown while converting (assigning value) (i.e. when [TypeConverter.ConvertFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb260h9b.aspx) is called) to a property in the property grid (for example, InvalidCastException), then you can catch in the [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) for that property.

```
class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            // Process the exception (for example, Log(e)) or Debug.Assert()
            throw;
        }
    }
}

// Using the TypeConverter in your class
class MyClass
{
    [ReadOnly(false)]
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    [DisplayName("Property 1")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
    public int Property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You can also override other methods of the base [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) class accordingly.

Going by the example, that you have added, it looks like you want the to deduce the reason why the communication with the device has failed (port not open, etc.). Then why not set a property or flag (for example, `Error` or `CommunicationError`) in the `Device` class that tells whether the specific error has occurred.

Then in the `TypeConverter` check for this property before accessing other properties, if in error then simply return from the `ConvertFrom()` without calling the `base` implementation. If the error is recoverable, which in your case appears to be a communication error, then allow the user to retry, rather than throwing an exception.

In addition, if you are mapping the device parameters directly onto the class and you have a property that you use in the property grid but do not want it to be written on the device, then mark it with a custom attribute (say boolean `DeviceWritable`). In the communication layer (where you actually write the values to the device), check for this custom attribute, if it is set as `true` then write to the device otherwise do not write to the device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I think it will rescue me from all these problems that i have with additional comboboxes, textfields e.c. ;) but i still have to find a way to get rid of these exceptions that came directly from my device.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the example given though I not sure why the `device` is throwing an exception! In case of error, you should have an error flag(s) or register(s) on the device that indicate error and its type.

Comment: The reason that device throwing an exception is mostly a malfunction of communication. So if the bytes that i read are unexpected, then either my machine is not on or it is running slow or my RS232 cable is burned up, e.c... So in some errors, i'm sure that even the DeviceWritable method won't work. I think i have the register that you mentioned. For all expectable (forseen) errors, i have a method to read errors from the device. But for unexpectable (really stupid and buggy) ones, i must throw these exceptions i guess.

Comment: So the exception is during the `communication` between the PC and the device, and not in the device itself? If correct, then the communication must not be handled in the property grid (representing the `device`). The population of the values into the `device` instance by reading from the device should be done by a separate `Communication` class.

Comment: So what i need is, a Comm class in addition to Device and Winform. So that i can throw the exceptions in Comm and catch in Device. Correct?

Comment: In that case the `Communication` class will have to check for the validity of the read value before updating the `device` instance. Note that you can update the values of the `device` instance by using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) rather than validating each property individually.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were more than helpful.